# Retain environment variable values for Symfony2 app development in Docker

Tags: php, symfony, docker, environment-variables

I have a Symfony2 app running inside Docker container. The parameters.yml file is set to pick environment variables as following:

```
framework:
    secret: "%env.secret%"
    ...
```

The Docker compose file contents are:

```
services:
    my-website:
        env_file: my-website.env
        build: .
        expose:
            - "80"
        volumes:
            - .:/app
```

The environment variables file is:

```
SYMFONY__ENV__SECRET=1234567890
...
```

Everything works fine when accessed via "app.php". However when accessed in dev mode (via app_dev.php) it fails to pick the environment variables. Is there any way to use the environment variables? I do not want to create another parameters.yml file with hardcoded values. Than you!